# Ruby on Rails RESTful controller function order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to rails and have been going through the process of building a REST service.  In the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) it seems pretty specific when they tell you where in the controller class to add their functions: create after new, show before new, etc.  I guess I was just curious if there is some convention that most people use for ordering (when I `rake routes` the order is: index, create, new, edit, show, update, destroy).  Not that its a big deal as long as your project is consistent, but is there a "conventional order" that people use?  If not, I guess we could all argue about who's order is better.

Thanks!

Comment: One thing to note is that `rake routes` has _nothing_ to do with your controller code.  The routes in there come from your `config/routes.rb` file and do not necessarily correspond to your controllers.

Comment: Yeah, but adding a resource to the routes.rb file makes rake spit out those routes in that order.  Thanks for the clarification though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of controller actions isn't really important at all, but I generally follow the same convention that Rails uses in it's own scaffolded controllers.

This way, I can easily scan to the controller action I'm looking for when I open a controller file.

Index, Show, New, Edit, Create, Update, Destroy

I think this order makes sense, as `index` and `show` are both concerned with "Showing" or "Reading" data, a primary concern in a web app.

Then `new` and `edit`, and `create` are concerned with "Creating", so they should be grouped together.

After `create` is `update`, which are usually very similar.

Then there's `destroy`, which is usually very simple and the only action of it's kind.

When adding custom actions to a controller, I keep them near the action they are most like, in terms of interactions.

If I have a method that is to display a subset or collection of things, I'll put it under `index`. If I have actions to `upvote` or `downvote` things, I think those fit nicely under `update`, since they are updating some part of the record.

Comment: Awesome.  I was thinking about similar groupings.  I know order is definitely less important than consistency, and none of this really gets in the way of functionality, but I thought it was an interesting topic.

Answer (score 2):

Totally a personal decision but I do have a way that I set up my controllers:

```
def index end 
def show end 
def new end 
def create end 
def edit end 
def update end
def destroy end
# non-restful endpoints/actions
```

For me, I like new/create and edit/update together since they, essentially, fire one after the other (when you are on the edit view, you're typically going to update the record, etc.).

Ultimately, I think having a system that works for you that you can follow and stay with is most important.